# Add marker to mapsactivity with firebase database

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase, unfortunately instead off showing markers, it just showed map without markers and crashed(Force Close). Can you show me the solution to solve this ?

Here is my MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.rizkafs.laundrize;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.content.res.Resources;
        import android.location.Criteria;
        import android.location.Location;
        import android.location.LocationManager;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
        import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;

        import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

        import java.util.ArrayList;


        public class NearbyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

            private static final String TAG = NearbyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
            private GoogleMap mMap;

            Double latitude;
            Double longitude;
            String namaTempat;
            String alamat;
            String jenis;
            String harga;
            String jamOperasi;
            String noTelp;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby);
                // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

                mMap = googleMap;

                try {
                    // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
                    // in a raw resource file.
                    boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                            MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                                    this, R.raw.style_json));

                    if (!success) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
                    }
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
                }

                DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child("places").getChildren()){
                            latitude = child.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                            longitude = child.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                            namaTempat = child.child("nama_tempat").getValue(String.class);
                            alamat = child.child("alamat").getValue(String.class);
                            jenis = child.child("jenis").getValue(String.class);
                            harga = child.child("harga").getValue(String.class);
                            jamOperasi = child.child("jam_operasional").getValue(String.class);
                            noTelp = child.child("no_telp").getValue(String.class);

                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(latLng)
                                    .title(namaTempat)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.laundry)));
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
                if(location != null) {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                            .zoom(17)
                            .build();
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is my database in Firebase

**Database Structure**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code and its working fine at my end. If crash issue persist at your end then try once with below version in app gradle.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```